# VS2017 Publishing Core Web Api Targeting full framework

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

Publishing a .Net Core Web Api project ,( *`Framework Depended Deployment`*)

1. If I target `Full Framework` ie net456, this will publish all framework DLLs in `net462` folder under `bin\Release`

   WebApp.csproj

   ```xml
     <PropertyGroup>
       <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
     </PropertyGroup>
   ```

[image]

2.If I target `Core 1.1` ie netcoreapp1.1, this will publish only application DLLs in `netcoreapp1.1` folder under `bin\Release`

```
WebApp.csproj
```

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

[image]

What is the reason for this behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking into the wrong folder, the published output should be in `bin\Release\netcoreapp1.1\publish`.

The normal build output doesn't contain the dlls because .NET Core can look up referenced DLLs from the global NuGet packages cache. The `.runtimeconfig.json` will specify the location of this cache on your machine so the DLLs don't need to be copied for every build.

.NET Framework however does not have this logic so the DLLs need to be copied to the build output.

Additionally in .NET Core 2.0, most of the NuGet packages you'll use for ASP.NET Core application are part of the runtime package store included in .NET Core 2.0, so you'll only publish assemblies that are not part of this store.
Since this store isn't available to .NET Framework, this mechanism can't be used for .NET Framework applications and all assemblies are part of the published output.

Comment: Do you know any reason why it was designed like that, because in FDD I expected to have only project DLLs in the publish folder. BTW VS2017 does not generate a publish folder under `Release\[framework]`

Comment: yes vs 2017 uses some other `PublishOutput` folder or similar under `Release` . The publish result includes the full dependency closure of a project to be able to run. This means everything is included that is not part of the runtime and the runtime store.